# onErrorResumeNext called when no exception generated

Tags: rx-java2

The following is a stripped down version of my code:

```
var obs = Observable.just(MessageResponse())

return obs.onErrorResumeNext(
    // handle error
).doOnComplete {
    // successfully completed
}
```

The observable is run from inside a flatMap (not shown). The onErrorResumeNext gets called yet it isn't clear why. If I replace it with a doOnError, no exception is generated and the code runs successfully. What could be causing the onErrorResumeNext to be called?

Comment: How do you know `onErrorResumeNext` is running? What do you have there at the "// handle error"? Do you have something like `onErrorResumeNext(handleError())` where `handleError` is executed by Java, even without RxJava present like you'd just write `handleError();`?

Comment: Placing a breakpoint in the onErrorResumeNext gets called. It doesn't matter what I have in the error handler. The fact is, that it should not be called, yet it is.

Comment: That makes no sense. How do you place a breakpoint there? Like on the line that has onErrorResumeNext? That executes when you assemble the flow, way before it even runs. Do you place it inside the lambda handler?

Comment: The problem turns out to be one of the dumbest problems that have plagued me since learning Kotlin. Squirrley braces "{ }" have to be used with onErrorResumeNext. I have round braces "( )". That causes the onErrorResumeNext to be called. Squirrly braces create an anonymous callback function. This is what happens when you look at a lot of Java code showing examples and those examples used ( ).